# How to stub methods of global variables with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, analytics, rspec-rails

I have a Rails project in which I an analytics library to track actions in different parts of the code. My initializer code looks like this:

```
# config/initializers/analytics.rb
Analytics = SuperAnalytics.new({
                                   api_key: '[SECRET]',
                                   on_error: Proc.new { |status, msg| print msg }
                               })
```

And my controller code looks like this:

```
def register
  email = params[:email]
  return unless email.present?
  Analytics.identify(
      user: email,
      parameters: {
          email: email,
      }
  )
end
```

My test code:

```
context '#register' do
  it 'should create an identify tracking event' do
    get :register, email: 'test@test.com'
    response.status.should == 200
    Analytics.should_receive(:identify)
  end
end
```

My test fails with

```
Failure/Error: Analytics.should_receive(:identify)
   (#<SuperAnalytics:0x007f8354594ac8>).identify(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

Is there a problem with stubbing methods of global variables that are initialized in initializers? Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put the expectation to the beginning

```
context '#register' do
  it 'should create an identify tracking event' do
    Analytics.should_receive(:identify)
    get :register, email: 'test@test.com'
    response.status.should == 200
  end
end
```

Otherwise, you're saying that "Analytics should receive this message while executing the following code", but there's no following code.

For example, see the [rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message):

[image: rspec example]

Comment: Thanks! This proves that writing code at 3AM is not a best practice :)